# Double hop issue? - SSIS gives access denied when writing to a flat CSV file on a network share

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm hoping someone can help me resolve and issue I'm running into.  I have a user run app that calls an SSIS package to create a CSV file on a network file share.  The app then processes the CSV file.  This had been working but then we started getting an Access denied error coming from the SSIS package.  The app it self is able to read/write to the file and the directory.  When I run the SSIS package in Visual Studio on a VM then the package is able to create the output file and the app can process it.  I was getting issues even reading the file from TSQL.  I have been working with our support staff to edit the user delegation settings in Active Directory and I have gotten to the point where I can use TSQL to read the CSV file without issues.  If I start the SSIS job using TSQL the job runs without errors.  When I execute the package from the App using DT_EXEC then I get access denied.  When I start the job using SSMS, I get access denied.  I'm thinking this is still a double hop issue.

The msDS-allowedToDelegateTo setting on both server A and file server B are:

**server A (running SQL Server and SSIS):**

- cifs/VM-SQL-B
- cifs/VM-SQL-A.Domain.Biz
- cifs/VM-SQL-A
- cifs/VM-SQL-B.Domain.Biz
- WSMAN/VM-SQL-B.Domain.Biz
- HOST/VM-SQL-B
- MSSQLSvc/VM-SQL-A.Domain.Biz:1433
- MSSQLSvc/VM-SQL-B.Domain.Biz:1433

**server B (File server):**

- cifs/VM-SQL-A.Domain.Biz
- cifs/VM-SQL-A
- cifs/VM-SQL-B.Domain.Biz
- cifs/VM-SQL-B
- WSMAN/VM-SQL-A.Domain.Biz
- HOST/VM-SQL-A
- MSSQLSvc/VM-SQL-A.Domain.Biz:1433
- MSSQLSvc/VM-SQL-B.Domain.Biz:1433

I looking for input as to what I am missing.

Thanks much,

Comment: Yep, definitely double hopping. You need to ensure the server the instance is on allows kerboros authentication to be passed on. When the package is run from Agent there isn't a "double hop" as Agent is running the service directly that runs the package but when you use T-SQL there is, as you are authenticating first to the SQL Server, and then to the share (as the access to the share uses *your* credentials).

Comment: Thanks, actually it doesn't work when I start the package from TSQL either.  It looks like it worked but that's only because there was no data to write.  I can read a CSV file with plain TSQL however.  So maybe it's something to do with write permissions.  Not sure what the deal is yet.

Comment: This still sounds like double hop.